# Perfect way of detecting mobile phones

Tags: php

I had been researching in the internet, and now I have still not found a solution. I want to detect people using a mobile phone, either is it iOS, Android or something else. So is there any way to detect all people who are using a mobile phone and entering the website and we could re-direct them to the mobile version of the website?

Comment: Downvoters, please state why you downvoted.

Comment: I suggest you use an existing solution like [Mobile_Detect class](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) for this purpose.

Comment: I downvoted because one requirement of this site is to do some basic research. Had you done so you'd have quickly found at least four sites with solutions for Javascript or PHP and a number of questions on [so] on this very topic.

Comment: This might help - http://mobiledetect.net/

Answer (score 0):

For mobile projects, we use WURFL: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/